# SOAP fault, deserialization failed

Tags: soap, soapfault

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <s:Fault>
            <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">
                a:DeserializationFailed
            </faultcode>
            <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">
                The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the 
                message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter
                http://URI/v1:Input. The InnerException message was \'\'EndElement\' 
                \'Input\' from namespace \'http://URI/v1\' is 
                not expected. Expecting element \'Username\'.\'.  Please see 
                InnerException for more details.
            </faultstring>
        </s:Fault>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

That is the fault I am receiving, here is the request I am sending:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:tns="uri" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasisopen.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract">
    <soap:Header></soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <tns:LogIn xmlns:tns="uri" xmlns="uri">
            <tns:Input>
                <tns:Username>user</tns:Username>
                <tns:Password>pass</tns:Password>
            </tns:Input>
        </tns:LogIn>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Note that "uri" in both cases was inserted for privacy purposes (real uri's are present in the request/response). I don't know much about SOAP - if someone could point me in the right direction as to whether there is something plainly wrong with my request?

Comment: Looks like a schema validation error. The client code does not match to the server side. What happens, if you send out the request without the <tns:Input> and </tns:Input> (but leave the content in between) ?

Comment: The message I get in that case is faultcode: `s:SessionService.INPUT_INVALID.RequestUndefined` faultstring: `Request cannot be blank. Please provide request details.`. 

In PHP I have the regular old soap client working just fine, I should note that the implementation above is written in node using the node-soap module. I dunno if that will provide any clues.

Comment: hmm strange.. did you already try to import the wsdl into soapui and compare the generated soap-result with your request?

Comment: Nope I did not do that. I'm not very familiar with SOAP - I'll try that out and report back.

Comment: hi   @jonathonh did you find the solution for the above issues ,actually I also got the same Issues.It will be great if could share ur views on this..Thanks .